# Is it possible to merge branching paths to transform as one object?

Tags: vector, inkscape, path, isometric

Due to the SVG format, Inkscape users cannot connect more than two paths to one node. As a result, I'm struggling to think of a method of connecting up my 'road' map below.

[image: Individual path object I wish to transform as one object.]

Ideally, I want a way to turn these separately sketched paths into one editable object. The reason is that I'm attempting to make an isometric road map - I planned on sketching it out, combining them, applying a stroke; stroke to path, transform to isometric projection. If anyone has any ideas on how better to do this, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge *all** vector editing software limits anchor points to only two path segments, an in and an out. There's simply no way to have *any* anchor be the basis of more than 2 path segments.

If you want one object, then expanding the paths/strokes to shapes, then merging shapes would create one object. However, then you will have a *shape* not stroked paths.

Answer (score 1):

That's is what groups are for, use  **Object > Group**.

Answer (score 0):

To combine these into a single editable object, use Path > Combine.

Note that, as already mentioned, paths cannot branch out, so it's not possible to 'glue' the ends to the middle of another path. However, a path can consist of multiple subpaths.